# why the span doesn't have the border bottom under IE7?

Tags: html, css

http://phplist.xxmn.com/node/1

why the two  red box  which locates at the center of the page(under Tags:) doesn't have the border bottom? the two red box html label is

```
<span>
```

and i applied the

```
        border:1px solid red;
```

to it.  but under IE7, the border bottom isn't show, firefox is ok. the out div box (the id=vistor_comment)is too heigh than under firefox? why? how to alter it. thank you.

Answer (score 6):

try giving it also `display: inline-block;`

I think it is because the line-height in which the span resides is lower than the height of the span including border, and so the lowest few pixels are cut off, in this case just enough for your bottom border to disappear.

Comment: i add this display: inline-block; the bottom can show? what causes the bottom-line disappeared? and how to make the out div box (the id=vistor_comment)to show normal,which is heigher.

Comment: span by default is an `inline` element which means that it has to concur with aspects that define lines. If your `line-height` is lower than the intended height of the span, the span will not fit in the line and the lower part of it will be cut off. I'm not sure what you mean with the second part of your comment. How does it show now and what would you like it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your parent container has a `height: 20px;`, I'm assuming that is and your various paddings are causing a height issue in IE7, therefore cropping a portion of your child container. Set an IE7 specific height to see if it rectifies the issue.